# Divisibility of Binomial Coefficients by a Composite Number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

I am aware of proof of divisibility of binomial coefficients of a prime $p$.  I've seen it is easy to show that when $0<k<p$
$$\binom{p}{k}\equiv 0 \mod p$$

Can there be anything stronger.  Suppose I have an integer $n=pq$.  Can we prove that  $p|\binom{pq}{k}$.  I feel like this is an impossibility since, looking at a case like $n=15$, $3|\binom{15}{4}$, but $3\not|\binom{15}{3}$.  $5|\binom{15}{3}$ but $5\not|\binom{15}{5}$.  Yet there ARE binomial coefficients where that 15 divide evenly.

Is there a way to determine which coefficients will successfully be divided by $n$ and which will be divisible by $p$ or $q$?  And are there stronger divisibility laws for powers of a prime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n = pq$, then $p$ divides $\left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right)$ if $p$ does not divide $k$, and sometimes in some other special cases. For example $3$ divides $\left( \begin{array}{c} 12 \\ 6 \end{array} \right)$.

The full answer: write the base $p$ expansions of $n$ and $k$:

\begin{align*}
n & = n_mp^m + \cdots + n_1p^1 + n_0 \\
k & = k_mp^m + \cdots + k_1p^1 + k_0 \\
\end{align*}

Then $p$ divides $\left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right)$ if and only if there exists some index $i$ with $k_i > n_i$.  This follows from [Lucas' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem).  In particular, since $p$ divides $n$, $n_0 = 0$, and so $p$ will always divide $\left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right)$ as long as $p$ does not divide $k$.